# Convert PDF/PS to straight line segments

Tags: pdf, converters, ghostscript, postscript

Is it possible to use Ghostscript (or another tool) to convert a source PS/PDF file into some format that consists of straight line segments.  **That is, I'm looking for an operation that is an analog of rasterization, but instead of pixels, results in line segments.**  For example a circle in PS/PDF would be converted to a regular polygon of some order (that's hopefully configurable).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with any current Ghostscript device. You could write a device to do so, but it would be fairly complex. Perhaps if you said why you need this a better solution could be proposed.